# Two TableViews that have same prototype cell, constraints behave differently

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I created two ViewControllers and two TableViews. Then i added prototype cell to one TableView, set it up according to my needs, copied it to the other TableView, changed its class and identifier and linked it up in ViewController that is datasource and delegate for each one.

The problem is, FEEDING one is behaving good, having constraints as expected, and the WALKING one is not, but i have no idea why since they have all same properties in each one's:

**ViewControllers:**

*FEEDING*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myFeedingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedingcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedingCell

        cell.time.text = self.vremena[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

*WALKING*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myWalkingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("walkingcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WalkingCell

        cell.time.text = self.vremena[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

**CustomCell files**

each one is connected to its class
FeedingCell is class of feeding prototype cell
WalkingCell is class of feeding prototype cell

**Constraints**

and the constraints are same, as you can see on the picture.

Here is the image providing different results and constraints:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXRFY.png)

Comment: have you set automatic dimension? or may be the cell/row height is different for tables or cells.

Comment: do you set rowHeight for the tableView?

Comment: okay rowHeight solved the problem. Thanks, completely forgot about tableView settings and focused on the cells only

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing rowHeight settings in TableView. Thanks @SilentLupin